# How do I serve image and pdf files, common to multiple domains, on a virtual host apache machine

Tags: php, apache, file, share

I have a virtual machine setup to host 4 domains, running fine (non-prod environment). There are image files and pdfs common between all domains. To save uploading the same files to each domain I want to have folders above the root folder of each domain i.e. all folders /var/www/html/in here (domain1,domain2,photos,pdf,dbconn, etc), I have done this with my PHP database scripts and they work fine, getting forbidden/permission error when I click on links. From my research, I've identified I need to modify httpd.conf and or httpd-vhosts.conf not totally sure which or both and not sure what the modification should be, also believe I should steer away from htaccess. (I have access to these conf files, I'm a PHP developer and don't usually play with Apache) Hoping this makes sense to someone and able to get some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

grant access to whatever directory the images and pdfs are stored in, access can be granted in each virtual host individually or in your main apache config file once, something like this...

```
<Directory "folder/subfolder/noobfolder">
 Grant access all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I've defined the root folder and the folder to find the files in PHP using  `define("ROOT", realpath(__DIR__ . "/../")); define("ROOT_PRIVATE", realpath(ROOT . "/isolated/"));` and added your suggestion to httpd.conf (needed to update to 'Require all granted'). Clicking on a link shows the full path but not serving the file "file not found" error. Apache 2.4.46 added `<Directory "/var/www/html/isolated">
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>`  `href="'.ROOT_PRIVATE.'/photo.jpg"` url response is `http://myurl.com/var/www/html/isolated/photo.jpg`, restarted Apache after mods

Comment: All sorted - set up Alias in httpd.conf and the respective `<Directory>` directives